# Git tag --contains [hash] delivers unexpected result

Tags: git, git-log, git-tag

I have a change with hash [hash] that was merged to production branch on May 27th. On June 5th, the release with tag x.x.3 was released. On June 24th, the release with tag x.x.4 was released. This shows in correct order in git log.

However, when I execute git tag --contains [hash], tag x.x.3 is not listed - the commit shows only in tags x.x.4 and higher.

Does anyone know where this difference could come from and why x.x.3 is not listed under the tags containing our commit?

Comment: Your implying (and so, it appears, assuming) that the dates of commits and merges are sufficient to understand which commits are parents of other commits.  In general, it's not; there isn't enough information here about how your branches are managed and how the releases were created for us to know.  The most obvious possibility would be if a release branch from the production branch was created before the change was merged in, and the release in question was the result of that branch (even though it was released later).  You can probably get better info with `git log --graph`

Comment: I'd be inclined to say that you are mistaken.  That the commit is actually not part of that release. Is there any way you can show us an actual log from your branches?

Comment: Thanks, Mark, you are correct. What I missed in the log is that it's the tags that are incorrect. The x.x.3 is properly tagged as a patch. The x.x.4 should however be a minor version (x.x+1.0), as it contains the merge of the development (next) with new features into master (production).

The commit in question should have been a patch as well, but was committed directly to development instead, causing the confusion, which `git log --graph` correctly shows as running parallel.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Mark Adelsberger, `git log --graph` held the entire story.

At the time when the commit was made, we were using git flow, with `master` and `development` branches running in parallel. We are fairly strict as far as commits go - we create a ticket that's either a bugfix, a hotfix or a feature, then commit the code belonging to them to corresponding branches. In the above case, though, two mistakes happened:

1. the commit in question was committed directly to development, without a separate branch and without proper documentation and code review (which triggered the incident in the first place)
2. whereas 3.2.3 was correctly tagged as hotfix (patch), the following release tag 3.2.4 should have been a minor release 3.3.0, as it contained new features and the merge of development to master (release). This caused me to incorrectly assume that the commit should have been included in the previous hotfix already.